# Android: Can An Activity Class Serve As A Context And FragmentActivties As Controllers?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I am making an Android app and working on setting up an appropriate design pattern to delegate responsibilities.

Its become clear that Android functions differently than iOS, in that you can only have one Activity active at a time and you cannot retain references to activities, you can only communicate through bundle passing.

With that in mind I am thinking of setting up an MVC kind of pattern as follows:

MainActivity as an Activity class that serves as a context(or 'master controller')

All other classes will be FragmentActivity classes which are 'controllers'.

The MainActivity class will then just swap in and out fragments as necessary but will also be able to reference and pass data to those fragments.

Is this safe design practice or have I missed how to properly setup MVC in Android?

Comment: A `FragmentActivity` is not a `Fragment`. A `MainActivity` might "just swap in and out fragments", but you actually need to have fragments to make that work.

Comment: Well yes the Fragment is the view, the FragmentActivity is the controller yes?

Comment: You are welcome to say that, though I wouldn't, and it does not fit with what you have written in your question. To be blunt, it feels like you have never written an `Activity`, nor a `Fragment`, nor a `FragmentActivity` in your life. Stop worrying about architecture until **you have learned the framework**. For example, I have never written an iOS app in my life, and I wouldn't *dream* of trying to impose a particular architectural pattern on an iOS project until I had *months* of experience in iOS development.

Comment: Yes I 100% agree with you. But as it stands I have 28 days to port something to Android so trying to weigh speed vs quality. I have written some activities and fragments but I ran into issues with their lifecycle (a lot of ''Performing stop of activity that is not resumed' errors). Regardless, I am investing a LOT of time into research and testing before I buckle down. If you have a particular resource that you reccomend for getting a better understanding of the framework I am all ears. Thank you.

Comment: "But as it stands I have 28 days to port something to Android" -- all the more reason to quit worrying about MVC and get something written. Trust me when I say that most Android apps in existence have not been written with MVC, or any particular GUI architectural pattern, explicitly in mind. "I have written some activities and fragments but I ran into issues" -- none of which you have asked about here on SO, from what I can see.

Comment: As the communication between Activities and Fragments seem to be a major concern for you, I will just mention that you might benefit from looking at EventBus. It is a really easy concept to understand and lets you pass complex objects  anywhere in your code without having to worry about Bundles or the like. butterknife is another tool that could save you some time as well of you have a lot of views.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see you have an indepth book published! I'm going to take a look at that!